# Python Boto created cloud-init #include script not running on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, user-data, cloud-init

I've run out of ideas, would appreciate some help.

I'm starting and EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 instance and adding the following script to the user data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET = 'myBucket'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MyAccessId'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'MySecretKey'

s3 = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
install = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='bash1.txt',     force_http=True)
config = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='cloud-config.txt', force_http=True)
start = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='bash2.txt', force_http=True)

sys.stdout.write("#include\n")
sys.stdout.write(install+"\n")
sys.stdout.write(config+"\n")
sys.stdout.write(start+"\n")
```

After the instance has started, I can right click on the instance and View Sys Log.

I can see the following near the bottom:

```
Generating locales...
en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
    #include
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
```

I can run wget from the instance on the provided url's and see the contents of the txt files.

Why aren't the scripts added via #include working? Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
C

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, you're just one layer too deep :)

With Ubuntu and cloud-init, your user data can be an executable script OR it can be a CloudConfig file.

In your question, you are passing a python executable as your userdata. On the Ubuntu machine, it sees an executable program (because it starts with `#!`) and it runs it. And that's all it will do. It won't process the output of your program.

What you want, is to run the python script on YOUR computer, and use the OUTPUT of the program as your userdata.

So in your example, the userdata passed to Amazon should be:

```
#include
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
http://nerdcloudinit.s3.amazon...
```

cloud-init on Ubuntu will see the first line `#include` and know that it needs to download the files. Then, it will look at each file it downloads to process each one.

The mime-multipart is only useful if you want to lump multiple files together into one. For example instead of downloading three files from S3, you could put them all together into one file and `#include` a single URL. You don't need that here though.

The link you included for cloud-init docs http://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit has more examples of what your userdata can contain.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I've made some progress on this. When combining CloudInit user data input formats, you have to pass it as a Multipart Input.

From the [docs](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit)

> A single format of user data might not be enough to accomplish what you want. For example, you may want to insert an upstart job and also run a user-data script.
>
> There is a tool in cloud-init's tools/ directory called 'write-mime-multipart' which can aid creating mime multipart content.

The multipart version of the above script, generated using *write-mime-multipart* looks something like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============7017068435702325667=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============7017068435702325667==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myPythonUserDataScript.txt"

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET = 'myBucket'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'MyAccessId'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'MySecretKey'

s3 = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
install = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='bash1.txt',     force_http=True)
config = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='cloud-config.txt', force_http=True)
start = s3.generate_url(300, 'GET', bucket=AWS_BOOTSTRAP_BUCKET, key='bash2.txt', force_http=True)

print '--===============7017068435702325667=='
print 'Content-Type: text/x-include-url; charset="us-ascii"'
print 'MIME-Version: 1.0'
print 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'
print 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myIncludeFile.txt"'

print "#include"
print install
print config
print start
print '--===============7017068435702325667==--'
```

Haven't gotten it to work yet, but it's a step in the right direction.

During my search I've also come across two useful tools for starting configured minions on EC2, namely

1. [Salt Cloud](https://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
2. [Shaker](https://shaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)